# How to save files directely on local computer?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-11, mobaxterm

MobaXterm 20.6
My programs run on a ubuntu server (18.04.3 LTS).
The client is on Windows 11.\

The users have a home directory like `/home/ADNAME.LOCAL/userlogin` on the server.

The program is started by (MobaXterm) shortcut from Windows desktop.

If I want to save a file out of the program, it's written to `~` / `/home/ADNAME.LOCAL/userlogin`. If I browse through the directories, it starts at `/` on the server.

How can I access `C:\Users\userlogin\Desktop\` to save files to?

---

Some time ago, I started the program and it there where this path selected already. There the program is started by shortcut too. But if I opened MobaXterm, on the left there where the server files shown. On other computers not.

Comment: You want a remote Ubuntu server to access your local machines User profile directory?

Comment: @Ramhound  Yes, if possible over MobaXterm.